# Why writing a correct input uppercase throws an error?

Tags: python, lowercase

If user inputs a correct word  uppercase I get a "You made a mistake" response. Why does `user_choice.lower()` not work like I intended? Where did I make a mistake?

```py
import random

rock_paper_scissors = ("rock", "paper","scissors")
cpu_choice = random.choice(rock_paper_scissors)
user_choice = input("Rock, paper or scissors ? Enter your choice: ")


if user_choice.lower() != "rock" or "paper" or "scissors":
    print("You made a mistake. Please try again")
    user_choice = input("Rock, paper or scissors ? Enter your choice: ")

while cpu_choice == user_choice.lower():
    print ("--------------------------------------------------------")
    print(f"CPU: {cpu_choice.upper()} vs YOU: {user_choice.upper()}.  It's a tie. Try again!")
    print ("--------------------------------------------------------")
    user_choice = input("Rock, paper or scissors ? Enter your choice: ")
```

Comment: `if user_choice.lower() != "rock" or "paper" or "scissors"` is not the right way to check for more than one value.  See this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/494134

Comment: See @toRex 's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `if` you set isn't correct. Try instead

```
if user_choice.lower() != "rock" or user_choice.lower() != "paper" or user_choice.lower() != "scissors":
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean:

```py
if user_choice.lower() not in rock_paper_scissors:
    print("You made a mistake. Please try again")
```

Comment: Maybe even better: `if user_choice.lower() not in rock_paper_scissors:`, so we don't have to write those values again. With just three values performance is not an issue.